# Convert MongoDB character as R Date

Tags: r, mongodb, rmongo

I tried to convert MongoDB date to R date Object. I use

```
library(RMongo)
library(data.table)

mongo<-mongoDbConnect("test", host = "127.0.0.1", port = "27017")
event<-dbGetQuery(mongo, "event", "", 0, 1000)
data<-as.data.table(event)
```

date<-data$date return the vector:

```
[1] "Fri Oct 28 13:15:00 CEST 2016" "Fri Oct 28 16:00:00 CEST 2016" "Fri Nov 04 18:30:00 CET 2016"  "Fri Nov 04 18:45:00 CET 2016"
```

I am not able to convert this vector. I tried the following code:

```
as.Date(date, format = "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y")
[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA

strptime(date, format = "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y")
[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

I also tried to modify the format using

```
s.POSIXct(date, "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y")
Error in as.POSIXct.default(date, "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y")
```

Can someone kindly explain how I can achieve this, and explain what I am doing wrong ..

Many thanks in advance

Comment: you have a field in mongodb that stores date and now you want to read and convert it to R date. Am i Correct ?

Comment: Exactly, this field is a iso date in mongodb.

Comment: ok few examples for your reference 1. # mongo.bson.from.list automatically converts R primitive data types(integer, numeric, logical, character) into MongoDB data types.
# You have to make some extra job for Date types.
# To build bson with ISODate data you shoudl pass it as POSIXct object:
date_string<- "2014-10-11 12:01:06"
query<-mongo.bson.from.list(list(date=as.POSIXct(date_string,tz='GMT')))  # pay attention to timezone argument
# note, that internall MongoDB strores dates in unixtime format:
query

Comment: 2.  d <- as.integer(as.POSIXct("2016-11-11")) * 1000
data <- mong$find(paste0('{"dte":{"$gt": { "$date" : { "$numberLong" : "', d, '" } } } }'))

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am trying to understand yours examples to apply them on my context. To be sure, i am read-only on the mongo data base and i query the database to extract data.table event with a variable containing some date in the format "Fri Oct 28 13:15:00 CEST 2016".
I try to convert the date in POSIxct in R, but i have an error (return NA). Then if i understand your example i need to modify the query to mongoDB to convert Date ?

Comment: sounds like some idea. good luck. if my examples help you dont forget to give an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and I found 2 possible solutions:

1. You con use the library mongolite instead of RMongo, which gives you the dates in the format "2016-01-01 01:00:00". The you just format them, for example calling `format(yourTime, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS3")` to recover the millis.
2. Using both libraries, you can use the aggregation framework and in the project stage convert your date to string, for example like this:`"$dateToString": { "format": "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%L", "date": "$yourTime" }`, then you format them again like in the previous case.

I hope it helps.

Farewell